# bash loop trough variables

Tags: bash, script, environment-variables

if i have a bunch of variables in bash:

```
foo_1="path/1"
foo_2="path/2"
foo_3="path/3"
foo_4="path/4"
foo_5="path/5"
```

They all start with `foo_`.
Is there a way to loop trough them, and run a command on each of them?
I tryed it with regex

```
for i in [ $foo_.\+ ]
```

but that seems not to work.

For example if I want to run mkdir on all variables starting with `foo_`, how would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree wholeheartedly with @choroba's advice: dynamically-named variable names are a PITA to work with.

Nevertheless, there is a way with some special syntax:

```bsh
for var in "${!foo_@}"; do
    declare -n ref=$var
    mkdir -p "$ref"
done
```

results in

```
$ tree
.
└── path
    ├── 1
    ├── 2
    ├── 3
    ├── 4
    └── 5

6 directories, 0 files
```

[3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the manual says:

> **${!prefix*}**
> **${!prefix@}**
>
> > Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with *prefix*, separated by the first character of the IFS special variable. When ‘@’ is used and the expansion appears within double quotes, each variable name expands to a separate word.

and [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) documents:

`declare [-aAfFgiIlnrtux] [-p] [name[=value] …]`

> **-n**
>
> > Give each name the *nameref* attribute, making it a name reference to another variable. That other variable is defined by the value of *name*. All references, assignments, and attribute modifications to *name*, except for those using or changing the -n attribute itself, are performed on the variable referenced by *name’s* value. The nameref attribute cannot be applied to array variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array instead.

```
foos=(path/1 path/2 path/3 path/4 path/5)
```

To make all the directories, you can then

```
mkdir -p "${foos[@]}"
```

Or, if you want to do something one by one

```
for foo in "${foos[@]}" ; do
    mkdir -p "$foo"
done
```